# How to replace substring and all non-space contiguous characters with regex?

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have a string with some misformatted data.

```
"007>009 021>089,017,018,12 - ,1200EST -"
```

The substring `,1200EST` is an error and is likely data belonging to another variable. It's not yet clear how frequent this type of formatting error will be in the dataset, but since the format of the substring contains letters (which the string shouldn't have at all), I'd like to make that my search pattern for `gsub`. The catch is to get the rest of the substring, that is the preceding (or potentially trailing) digits and the comma, essentially everything between the spaces if letters are included. The catch is that the regex pattern has to be rather general, basically any series of letters and all non-space characters contiguous to the series of letters.

I have this:

```
gsub("\\s+.*[[:alpha:]].*\\s+", " ", h2)
```

Which doesn't work at all, returning:

```
[1] "007>009-"
```

How to format the regex pattern?

**EDIT**

The substring containing letters could also look like these:

" EST1200 "
" EST "
" -1500ABC "

Again, a substring delimited by spaces only, containing 1 or more letters contiguous with 0 or more other characters of any type.

Comment: Settled on splitting the string on single space, then using `grepl` to test for any substrings with `[[:alpha:]]` and subset accordingly.

Comment: Can you give maybe 4-5 examples that you feel might represent what you are looking for? And the results that you expect?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to lose the `",1200EST"`, you can use this:

```
s <- "007>009 021>089,017,018,12 - ,1200EST -"
gsub(",\\d+EST", "", s)
```

To also lose the trailing `" -"`:

```
gsub(",\\d+EST -", "", s)
```

For the leading `"- "`, like this:

```
gsub(" - ,\\d+EST -", "", s)
```

And so on.

If you think the letters might be something other than `"EST"`, 
you can just grab the letters like this:

```
gsub(" - ,\\d+[A-Z]+ -", "", s)
```

Comment: this definitely gets close, thanks. But it won't generalize quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the pattern `(.*),.*` and replacing with the first capture group.

```
input <- "007>009 021>089,017,018,12 - ,1200EST -"
gsub("(.*),.*", "\\1", input)

[1] "007>009 021>089,017,018,12 - "
```

### Demo

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen, thanks for the demo site. What does the pattern you suggested actually search for? I wish I were more fluent with regex, but as I read it: capture any number of any characters before a comma and there will be any number of any characters after the comma, but ignore those.

Comment: @ConnerM. The initial `.*` is _greedy_, and will eat everything up until the _last_ comma.

Comment: Maybe regex isn't the way to go, not sure. And not sure I explained the situation well enough. There's no guarantee of a the comma even being there. Only certainty with this formatting error: a string containing some letters, with (or without) preceding or trailing characters of any type, delimited by spaces.

Comment: You need to give us rules for the replacement.  If you can't even do this, then a regex can't be written.  Actually, there would not be _anything_ you can do.

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen, you're right. Again, not very fluent in regex. Help me out, is this a description of a regex rule: Replace with a single space " " any substring that, delimited itself by single spaces, contains some number of letters contiguous with 0 or more other characters of any type?

Comment: It would be better for you to show sample data, both positive and negative cases.